# Proof that {1, pi} generates the extension R/Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I was trying to find a counterexample for:
If E/K is a finitely generated extension then [E:K] must be finite

I know there is a proposition that states: E/K is a finitely generated extension and algebraic if and only if [E:K] is finite

So what i tried to do was find a non algebraic but finitely generated extension. Looking it up on the internet i found a claim that {1, pi} generates R over Q (and also [R:Q] is infinite). But I don't get how this can generate for example pi^2 since pi is transcendental to the rationals there is no way it could exists a,b in the rationals such that $\pi^2 = a * 1 + b * \pi$.

What I am missing?

PD: Yeah I know I should learn how to use Latex, but i do not, so sorry for the bad formatting.
PD2: I didn't mention anywhere but obviously E and K are fields and K is contained in E (otherwise it wouldn't make any sense)

Comment: PD: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\{1,\pi\}$ cannot be a basis of the vector space $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$, since the latter is not $2$-dimensional, as you said yourself. But $\mathbb Q[\pi]$ is an infinite-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R$. It contains all powers of $\pi$.

Comment: That's okay if you don't know LaTeX. For your question it mostly involves putting \$'s around your math expressions. I did one of them; you should note be able to do the others.

Comment: @JonathanZ Actually, the tutorial is quite helpful.

Comment: @DietrichBurde - I agree, and they should totally go give it a read. My strategy is to show them just how simple it can be, and if they're unwilling to even do that, it's clear just how little they'll consider the other users.

Comment: @JonathanZ I see, yes, this makes sense.

Comment: Cram245- Oh, you'll have to put a backslash in front of each "{" in Latex. That's a little bit in obvious.

Comment: You need to make sure you understand the difference between $E$ being a finite-dimensional *vector space* over $K$ and $E$ being a finitely-generated *module extension* of $K$.

Comment: "Looking it up on the internet i found a claim that {1, pi} generates R over Q" - where did you find this claim? It sounds like the kind of nonsense ChatGPT might make up.

Comment: @rogerl Did you mean to write  "finitely generated field extension over $K$" or "finitely generated algebra over $K$"? To me, "finitely generated module extension of $K$" would mean the same thing as "finitely generated vector space over $K$", since modules over a field are the same things as vector spaces.

Comment: $[\Bbb R:\Bbb Q]=\mathfrak{c}$ and $\{1,\pi\}$ is most certainly not a basis for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: As for the counterexample of "If $E/K$ is a finitely generated extension then $[E:K]$ must be finite", $K(x)/K$ may be a good one, where $K(x)$ is the fractional field of $K[x]$, the polynomials ring on $K$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes. Yes I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you mean finitely generated as a field extension. Then $K(T)$ (the field of rational functions) is a finitely generated field extension of $K$ which is never finite.

On the other hand, if $E/K$ is a field extension which is a finitely generated $K$-algebra, then it is finite (Zariski's Lemma).

Of course, the claim about $\pi$ is wrong.